# prestashop: How to get discount applied on cart line item individually?

Tags: prestashop-1.6

We are using prestashop 1.6.1.4.
How can I get the discount applied on cart line item individually?

That is: not the cart rules, but the specific price rules applied via the backoffice, via the price tab for the product, or in the "promotion" (discount in english?) Catalog rules.

Answer (score 0):

I found what I was looking for in the ps_order_detail table.
Basically, the reduction_percent and reduction_amount fields reflect what was set via the backoffice, pertaining the discount related to products only (not cart).